# Script or command to automatically change some stuffs in my C code?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have several C files. and I created a function which is named

```
X_STRING(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4);
```

I called this function too many times from different C files. I want to replace the calling of all these functions to X_STRING(arg1, arg2, (arg1) * 2, (arg2) * 3);

awk seems to be the solution but I don't know how to treat all the cases because I should consider the case where :

1. I call the function with new lines inserted in the code between differnet arguments

e.g.

```
X_STRING(
arg1, arg2,
arg3, 
arg4);
```

1. an argument contains a parenthesis :

e.g.

```
X_STRING(arg1, arg2, (arg3 - 4)*3, arg4);
```

Someone can point me to good tools to resolve my problem ?

Comment: Do you only have the above two scenarios or could there be more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind changing the format in the output, you might be happy with an m4 solution.  Put the following in a file:

```
define( X_STRING, ``X_STRING''( $1, $2, ($1) * 2, ($2) * 3 ))
```

And then run:

```
$ m4 def_file file.c
```

where file.c is your code and def_file is the name of the file with the above content.  (The name is irrelevant.)

This should work if your code is well-formatted.  (If you have unmatched parentheses, it will fail.)
This will change the whitespace, but otherwise should do what you want.

Comment: but I have a question, do you think that awk is able to do that too ?

Comment: I cannot see an easy awk solution.  Trying to match braces would be tough.  Consider input like: X_STRING( foo( a, b ), 1, 2, 3 );

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to **customize the GCC compiler** for that purpose, thru GCC plugins written in C or GCC extensions written in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)

The advantage of working inside the compiler is that you process some compiler's internal representation (like *Gimple* for GCC), and not only text. Textual approaches won't work that well if for instance the call to your `X_STRING` is appearing by expansion of a macro, or by inlining a function.

Extending the GCC compiler has also several drawbacks: it is GCC specific (and might even depend upon the version of GCC), and it would require several days of work.